# Install or Upgrade to PHP 7.2 from 7.0 on Debian 9

Tags: php, installation, upgrade

I am trying to install or upgrade whatever suits best from PHP 7.0 to 7.2. I'm facing below while running `sudo apt-get update`.

Would appreciate if someone could let me know how to proceed with this.

```
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository '//https://packages.sury.org/php stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 5):

I guess the line containing the repository has a typo. Is it `deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main`?
See the guide [Installing PHP 7.2 on Debian 9](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-on-debian-9/) (which works).

Comment: Thanks a ton...! This worked for me absolutely with no issues.

Comment: You saved a lot time....